# magento 2 theme inheritence

Tags: magento2

I want to inherit the existing blank or luma theme in magento 2. After installation, I copied the theme from `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2(root_directory)\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma` and pasted inside `app\design\frontend\package_name\theme_name` and also modified `theme.xml` `registration.php` `composer.json` according to my theme name. Now when I change the configuration at backend am able to see the theme in the browser. But there is no view(for layout) folder inside any of the module.

Is there any mistake in my method of inheriting the theme? or is there any solution? Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Official Docs:

- [Create a theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
- [More on theme inheritence](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html)

You don't need to copy files over to inherit a theme, you only need to create a few files/directories and tell Magento which theme you wish to inherit (set as a parent theme).

### Register your theme

The main file to register your theme is registration.php, without this Magento won't fully pick up on your theme. This files belongs in your theme's root directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>',
    __DIR__
);
```

Don't forget to replace `<Vendor>/<theme>` with your package and theme name.

### Set your theme's parent (where you inherit your files from)

To inherit a theme you need to specify it in app/design/frontend///theme.xml, this example sets Magento/luma as your parent theme so you will inherit all files from the Luma theme.

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/luma</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

The [official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) go into more details and should help you out. You can skip the Composer section ('Make your theme a Composer package') as this is optional.